# callback function as argument of window.requestAnimationFrame()

Tags: javascript

I have js file where I am using requestAnimationFrame(). I know that argument should be callback function. I think that my argument is callback function, but errors cames in js console:

> TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.requestAnimationFrame is not an
>   object.

file.js:

```
function screen(){
     console.log("it works!")
}

function fun(word){
    if (word === 'tree'){
        screen()
    }
window.requestAnimationFrame(fun("tree"));
```

everything works nice. I use it in my large project and everything works as I want, but I don't know why I have errors in js console

Comment: this isnt the way how you utilize `requestAnimationframe()` it is used to make sure that your animations run smoothly if you are using `javascript` for animations instead of `css` and it should be inside the `function fun()` and the call to `function fun()` should be after the declaration of the function, what are you using this function for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to handle this kind of thing is to wrap your call to `fun("tree")` inside an anonymous function, which becomes the callback that requestAnimationFrame can use:

```
function screen(){
     console.log("it works!")
}

function fun(word){
    if (word === 'tree'){
        screen()
    }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(function () { fun("tree"); });
```

This differs from your code in that you are passing in the result of calling the `fun` function with the parameter "tree".  As `fun` doesn't return anything that result is undefined.  It's as if you did

```
var x = fun("tree"); // x is undefined
window.requestAnimationFrame(x);
```

Answer (score 5):

You pass a result of the execution of `fun` function to the `requestAnimationFrame`, that's why you got an error (because it's returns an undefined).

Correct way to do it:

```
function screen(){
     console.log("it works!")
}

function fun(word){
    if (word === 'tree'){
        screen()
    }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(fun.bind(window, "tree"));
```

More information about `bind` you can find in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: I agree with this. The syntax for this function is window.requestAnimationFrame(callback); You should either only mention the function name here or use bind as explained above

Comment: Based on body of the function(they check for the parameter value and then call `screen` function) author probably looking for a bind, because just pass function of param will not apply to it logic.

Comment: should be    window.requestAnimationFrame.bind(fun("tree"));    Thank You for help! :)